# Android - Things Raspberry Pi - Google Mobile Vision Support

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi3, face-detection, android-things

I'm trying to run an android app on Android Things OS.
The app uses facial detection as a first step filter for reaching facial recognition.
The recognition process is made by a third party (remote) API, so there is nothing to worry about it, but the detection is being carried out by the Google Mobile Vision API for Android. The problem I'm facing is that the app crashes every time a camera preview is about to start.
The code of the app is derived from this example: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision (Face tracking). So if this code runs, my app runs. 
I also know that there is a known issue with the raspberry pi and the camera trying to create more than one output surface.
My questions are: 
(1) Is there a way to successfully run the code in the example https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision (Face tracking)?
(2) When is going to resolved that known issue?

Thanks in advance.

Attentive,

Gersain Castañeda.

Comment: How are we supposed to know when Google will fix a bug in their code?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Android Things([DP6](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html)) which is with API 27, supports the new camera API [Camera2](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) as its explained [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/android-things-developer-preview-6.html).

Camera2 API supports more than one output surface and its runnable on Android Things.

For getting more inspirations of how doing this check this [tutorial](http://werner-dittmann.blogspot.se/2016/03/using-androids-imagereader-with-camera2.html)(how to use camera2) and this very useful [sample](https://github.com/EzequielAdrianM/Camera2Vision)(how to use Google Vision).